# Passing Objects vs IDs

Tags: javascript, object

I have a general javascript question.

Let's say I have an array `persons` of `Person` objects. Each `Person` has an ID, names, adresses, etc.

In my functions that process `persons`, I usually pass the `Person` object I'm manipulating. However this somehow feels wrong. Like I'm wasting memory.

So my question:

- Am I using extra memory by passing the objects instead of just their ID's?
- Is using getPersonByID() and just passing ID's instead a better option?
- How do you go about managing many instances of objects?

Comment: In JS you are not passing the object you are passing a reference to the object so no big deal on memory matters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/518000/1529630)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I using extra memory by passing the objects instead of just their ID's?

No, you are passing a reference to the object, not a copy of it every time. So no extra memory is being used for each time you pass a `person` object around... So when you ask:

> Is using getPersonByID() and just passing ID's instead a better option?

Not really, as you will just add the overhead of having to go through you person list and retrieve the object again.

> How do you go about managing many instances of objects?

It depends on a lot of things, like scope, who is referencing, etc. I suggest you take a look at [how JS garbage collection and memory management works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) to have a better understanding at it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So even if I have the following:

Comment: So even if I have the following:

    var members = [];
    var activeMembers = [];

    members.push(new Person());
    members.push(new Person());

    activeMembers.push(members[0]);

The memory will only hold

* `members`object
* `activeMembers` object
* and two `Person` objects

Right? That's pretty cool.

Comment: Sorry, I thought block code would work. Anyways, thanks for your help

Comment: @whateverforever yes, it will have only these objects. And yap, that's  pretty cool indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

Object "values" in JavaScript are *references*. Passing an object to a function passes the reference to the object, and it's no more expensive than passing a string (like the id value) or a number.

To put it another way: passing or assigning an object value does **not** involve making a copy of the object.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, objects (object literals, arrays and functions) are all passed by reference. When you pass the object to a function, you don't copy it the way you usually do in C/C++. Instead you are passing a reference (Basically a second name of the object).

```
function func(object) { object.changed = true; }
let a = {};
func(a);
console.log(a.changed); //true
```

Passing an ID on the other side will be much more verbose, it actually creates extra overhead, and it's really up to you how you want to design your application.